# Define Google Maps before using its methods

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am following the google maps api documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

The define the USGSOverlay, which is a prototype of google.maps.OverlayView(), before their init method.

I have a separate html file and separate javascript file (Map.js), where I call the init method for the map.

```
  <div id="googleMap"></div>
  <script src="Map.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<YOURKEY>&callback=init"></script>
```

However, this throws an error that google is not defined in google.maps.OverlayView().

I know that I have to define my maps.googleapis.com before my Map.js, but if I do that, then the callback function is not defined since it is in the Map.js file.

How can I achieve this by keeping the html code and javascript code in different files?

**EDIT:**

So I followed the documentation in the link here for async defer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#sync

But I am still getting the error.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my javascript code in map.js is:

```
var map;
CustomImageOverly.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }

      function CustomImageOverly(bounds, image, map) {

        this.bounds_ = bounds;
        this.image_ = image;
        this.map_ = map;

        this.div_ = null;

        this.setMap(map);
      }
```

It displays the map correctly, but for the overlay, it still throws the error: google is not defined. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I tried the documentation but I am still getting the error. I have added more information in the question.

Comment: `callback=init` & `callback=initMap` - Which is the right one? You should put any google map code within the (right) callback function that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow), they are not loading the API asynchronously (with "async defer" and callback function), they are loading it synchronously.

To do that change your API include from:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

Then initialize the map when the DOM (and the API) has finished loading with:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```js
var map;
CustomImageOverly.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
  srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

  overlay = new CustomImageOverly(bounds, srcImage, map);
}

function CustomImageOverly(bounds, image, map) {

  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  this.div_ = null;

  this.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100% margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just wanted to add that I needed to add my map.js after the google api was added in html. Secondly, I think your google api key is still present in the answer, maybe remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Load your map.js after the googleapis script.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
```